# Separate values from a string and store it in a array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Sample string: `This is an inactive AAAAA product. It will be AAAAAA by AAAAA test1/test2 number ABCDEF123456/123456789 during execution`

I need to separate these values and store it in a array "`ABCDEF123456/1234567890`" these values will be in a array like`[ABCDEF123456,1234567890].`

```
Var str ="This is an inactive AAAAA product. It will be AAAAAA by AAAAA test1/test2 number ABCDEF123456/123456789 during execution";
var splitStr = str.split("/");
console.log(splitStr[1]); // ABCDEF123456
```

Here I'm getting "`ABCDEF123456`"

I need to achive like `ABCDEF123456/1234567890` would be `[ABCDEF123456,1234567890]`

Comment: what are the criteria to match ABCDEF123456/1234567890 but not test1/test2 ? `.match(/([0-9A-F]+)\/([0-9A-F]+)/).splice(1,2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` and `split`

```js
let str = `Text1/Text2 This is an inactive AAAAA product. It will be AAAAAA by AAAAA test1/test2 number ABCDEF123456/123456789 during execution`

let final = str.match(/(?<!\S)\w+\/\w+(?!\S)/g).map(v=> v.split('/'))

console.log(final)
```

---

If you just want pattern like `alphanumeric/numeric` the replace second `\w+` by `\d+`

```js
let str = `Text1/Text2 This is an inactive AAAAA product. It will be AAAAAA by AAAAA test1/test2 number ABCDEF123456/123456789 during execution`

let final = str.match(/(?<!\S)\w+\/\d+(?!\S)/g).map(v => v.split('/'))

console.log(final)
```

Comment: why split the result when you can just use regex groups to get directly what you want?

Comment: @Adassko what if there are several such patterns ? match do not returns all the captured group when we use `g` flag, notice the first snippet if i use captured groups i wont be able to get all the values using match.

Comment: you can use `matchAll` instead of `match` to work with `g` flag. for example: `[..."ABC/DEF GHI/JKL".matchAll(/(\S+)\/(\S+)/g)].map(x => x.slice(1,3))`. but the question was only about a single match I guess

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find that specific combination of Letters and numbers (6 letters, 6 numbers, a forward slash and 9 numbers at any point in any string I suggest you look into RegEx patterns. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

The pattern that you are looking would be something like

```
let re = new RegExp('[A-Z]{6}\d{6}/\d{9}');
```

Once you found that string you can easily split it by the `/` to get the list you are looking for.
I’m writing this on my phone so I haven’t been able to test it.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the question is not clear enough.
What is that you want to achieve?

Based on what I assumed, Here's how you can `split` the string into an array.

```js
var str = "ABCDEF123456/1234567890"
var seperated_array = str.split("/")

// [ABCDEF123456, 1234567890]
```